# path of the file which is uploaded through yii Cuploadedfile

Tags: yii, upload

I am curious . Is there any way to get the path of the uploaded file in yii . I Am using Cuploadedfile.

Comment: do you mean this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#tempName-detail ?

Comment: I wanted to know the path of the user side (From where the user is uploading a file). But i think that this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile, you can't get the file uploaded loaded location. But you should define the uploaded location and save the file name into database table as

```
$uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
$fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
        $model->image = $fileName;
        if($model->save())
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/images/products/'.$fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks man . It is clear that I have to make my own record on server. Can I make a folder on server by using mkdir() function before saving a file. Or there is a fixed name of folder and i cant change it??

Comment: yes, you can make folder using mkdir() but not necessary while you can't change. However, if you change folder name, you should change the folder name in path in script too. :)